# How do I make php's curl accept SSLv3?

Tags: php, curl, openssl

I have the following code:

```
curl_setopt($this->curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($this->curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,'all'); 
curl_setopt($this->curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    // set the file to be uploaded
    if (!curl_setopt($this->curl_handle, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp_to_download)) {
        throw new Exception("Could not download file $local_file");
    }

    // download file
    try {
        if (!curl_exec($this->curl_handle)) {
            throw new Exception(sprintf('Could not download file. cURL Error: [%s] - %s', curl_errno($this->curl_handle), curl_error($this->curl_handle)));
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $error_msg = $e->getMessage();
        // Fallback to cUrl upload
        if (strpos($error_msg, 'SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO')) {
            return $this->curlProcessHandler('ftp://'.preg_replace('#/+#', '/', $this->server.':'.$this->port.'/'.$remote_file), $local_file);
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Could not download file $remote_file: $error_msg");
        }
    }
```

When I have `curl_setopt($this->curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,'all');`, it returns the error:

```
Could not download file. cURL Error: [35] - error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

And when I have `curl_setopt($this->curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,'3');`, I get a different error:

```
Could not download file. cURL Error: [4] - OpenSSL was built without SSLv3 support
```

It seems like my version of OpenSSL doesn't support SSLv3, and I don't know how to fix this.
I've tried different methods of changing my openssl version, but none of them worked.

Comment: You don't. You update whatever is trying to use SSLv3 because it is hilariously and _dangerously_ out of date. For reference, SSLv3 support was removed from Firefox in November 2014 because of gigantic, unpatchable security holes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No longer supported see the curl docs for supported CURLOPT_SSLVERSION values link below.

SSLv2 is disabled by default since 7.18.1. Other SSL versions availability may vary depending on which backend libcurl has been built to use.

SSLv3 is disabled by default since 7.39.0.

https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSLVERSION.html

Comment: Thanks. I found a workaround to my issue that didn't involve php curl.